# Merging two views data in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have a query in Google analytics. I have two view (one for iOS & another android) in my Google Analytics account. Currently we have to select a view to get analytics information. I have gone below urls but could not get success

http://techin.oureverydaylife.com/merge-google-analytics-profiles-15349.html

So my question is that can we merge two view (iOS & Android) into Single/Master view?

Comment: Are you actually talking about views (in that case you could simply create a new view that has data from both OS, although that would not work for historical data).  In any case this is a reporting question and SO is usually reserved for programming questions (webmaster.stackexchange.com might be better suited for questions in the reporting interface).

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks for your reply. As as a developer, I was not aware of webmaster.stackexchange.com. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can roll up properties in one single property, but this is a Google Analytics 360 (premium) feature. Otherwise you have no access to this feature.

So if you have access you can simple navigate to the administration panel and select "Roll Up Management" from the properties menu.